# How to build a python package in a dev mode from source code with conda?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, anaconda, conda

I am working on an open source python project which depends on a lot of non-python packages (perl, r, ...). Consequently, they use conda to install the dependencies, as they can't be simply installed with pip.

You can run `$ conda install --channel bioconda <awesome_package>` to install the stable build of the package. I want to install it in the development mode. For a purely python project, I'd do something like this:

1. pull the source code from github
2. `$ cd path/to/awesome_package && pip install -e .`
3. run tests
4. modify the code
5. run tests
6. etc

In the step 2 above, the `pip` command installs all I need to work. It uses `setup.py` script to do its job, and `requirements.txt` together with `requirements_dev.txt` to install the dependencies. And, I don't need to rebuild/reinstall anything when I change something in the source code.

How do I do the same with `conda` instead of `pip`? How do you provide a list of requirements (python and non-python) to `conda`?

The most relevant thing I found is this: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/bpp.html 
However, with this approach I'd need to rebuild and reinstall the package locally very time I want to run the tests, which is something I'd like to avoid.

I am only going to change the python source code of the package I'm working on.

**TL;DR**: how to build a package with conda in a dev mode from the source code?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Conda has a `develop` command analogous to `setup.py develop`: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/build/conda-develop.html

Comment: @darthbirth could you please give an example of how to use it?

Comment: `$ cd path/to/awesome_package && conda develop .`

Comment: @darthbirth This doesn't work for me. Which files does conda require for this to work?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What error message do you receive? `conda develop` only needs a setup.py file. However, it will not install dependencies, those you have to `conda install` yourself.

Comment: The `conda develop` command is made available via the conda-build package: see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4560. You just need to do `conda install conda-build`